# Fast image preview in macOS context menu (right click)

Tags: macos, applications

There was a cool app on windows, I believe it was called FastPreview - when you right click an image, you will get the small image preview right in the context menu.

I find this very convenient. Is there anything like that on mac?

### Edit

I forgot to mention that I don't use Finder that much, but an alternative file manager. For that reason, I am asking this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac it's called **[Quicklook](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25575)** & is much more powerful than just a quick jpg preview, it can also preview text, pdfs, spreadsheets, audio, movies & even much more specialist data types - anything there's a plugin for.

There are two simple ways...

1. In column view a preview will always show to the right of the selected item. [This is a pref, accessed by hitting  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd>  from any open Finder window, but defaults to *on*]
   The size of the preview is dependant on the column width.

[image]

2. Alternatively, from any view, just tap the Spacebar - the preview will pop out at full size [or to fit screen]. You can resize by dragging a corner, same as any window.
   This usually has an 'Open With' choice at the top to go straight to the default app for that file type [circled in red].
   You can change the currently viewed item by changing your selection. You don't need to be able to see behind the preview for this, you can step around using the arrow keys.
   Pressing Spacebar a second time clears Quicklook.

[image]

Quicklook is also available from some other apps, such as Mail, for viewing attachments that don't auto-inline, like text files, or if the view is too small, for instance a pdf.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I don't use Finder that much. For that reason, I dont use this feature much, but you have me the idea.

Comment: Rather an important detail to miss out really :/

Comment: I know @Tetsujin, terribly sorry, I just use that other file manager that much that I 'forgot' finder is there. But again, I will mark this as a correct answer, as I don't see any other solution :)

Answer (score 0):

On your desktop or in finder app all you have to do is select an image or video file, then tap your spacebar on your keyboard.  This will open a quick preview window.  This also works with a bunch of other file extensions.